# How do I add a password field on registration form?

Tags: 7, users

I have a basic website, with nothing installed on it yet. My first task is to get my users to be able to register with a password. I see that certain "modules" will allow you to do this, but is a module really necessary to be able to register with a set password?

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Go to *Account Settings* (admin/config/people/accounts) and uncheck the *Require e-mail verification when a visitor creates an account* checkbox.

> With this setting disabled, users will be logged in immediately upon
>   registering, and may select their own passwords during registration.

If you want both (Password field + email verification), use the [User registration password](http://drupal.org/project/user_registrationpassword) module

Comment: Check also [Login Toboggan](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)